# How to hide TODOs of future dates in org-agenda weekly view?

Tags: org-agenda, todo

I like it when I enter the org-agenda weekly view and see the hourly view of my day with my recurring tasks that have specific time period of doing.

But since these tasks are recurring , I see them repeated for every day of the week.

Can I hide (like collapse) all these TODOs from future days and show only the ones for the current day?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```el
(setq org-agenda-show-future-repeats 'next)
;; or perhaps ...
(setq org-agenda-show-future-repeats nil)
```

The doc string of the variable (`C-h v org-agenda-show-future-repeats`) says:

```
org-agenda-show-future-repeats is a variable defined in ‘org-agenda.el’.

Its value is t

Non-nil shows repeated entries in the future part of the agenda.
When set to the symbol ‘next’ only the first future repeat is shown.
```